# Python - horizontal output, with braquets, commas and quotations marks

Tags: python-3.x

```
s = "That that occurs sometimes. It sometimes means that which, and sometimes just that"
target = "that"
words = s.split()
b = []
for i,w in enumerate(words):
    if w == target:
        if i > 0:
            b = words[i-1]
            print([b].sep="",end",")
```

"I used, end=",sep=",but nothing worked.I need the output horizontally, with square brackets, commas and quotations marks. the brackets appear in the middle, and a comma at the end."

"Current output"

> > > ['That'],['means'],['just'],

"I need this output"

> > > ['That','means','just']

Comment: Try appending the words to `b` inside the for loop instead of printing them, then after the loop, print the list `b`, you would get `['That', 'means', 'just']`

Comment: Do you mean you need a *list*?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this code it will work fine

```
s = "That that occurs sometimes. It sometimes means that which, and sometimes just that"
target = "that"
words = s.split()
b = []
for i,w in enumerate(words):
    if w == target:
        if i > 0:
            b.append(words[i-1])
print(b,sep="")
```